# Using MIN() to get the lowest value, but i got two rows?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a SQL question were I want to find the lowest value from the field `prod_week`.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
     MIN(oe.prod_week), oe.prodplan_id 
FROM 
    pd_mounting_details as md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    pd_order_eco AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id 
WHERE 
    oe.status = 4 
    AND (md.starttime = '' OR md.starttime IS NULL)
    AND (a.production_group = 4)  
    AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)) 
GROUP BY
    oe.prodplan_id
```

The result of this is

```
prod_week      |  prodplan_id
  1126         |     27
  1127         |     28
```

What I don't understand is why this result in two rows when I used `MIN(prod_week)` to get the row with the lowest week number.

If I remove the `prodplan_id` from the selection it all works and I get one row were `prod_week` is "1126". And from that all I want is to get the id `prodplan_id` to.

I hope this question isn't to blurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
select min(x),y
from table
group by y;
```

what you're doing is getting `y` and the smallest value of `x` for each **distinct** value of `y`.  So, since `prodplan_id` has values of 27 and 28 in your morass of joins, we have that the smallest value of `prod_week` that appears when `prodplan_id=27` is 1126, and the smallest value of `prod_week` that appears when `prodplan_id=28` is 1127.

ETA:  If you want one row, you could do an `order by 1 limit 1` at the end.

ETA^2:  You can also wrap things up in a subquery and use a where clause at the end:

```
select min_prod_week,prodplan_id
from(
    select min(oe.prod_week) as min_prod_week,oe.prodplan_id
    from....
    group by oe.prodplan_id
    )min
where min_prod_week=(select min(prod_week) from pd_order_eco)
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't understand the non-ANSI `LIMIT 1` - it's a proprietary MySQL extension only available in MySQL

Comment: Great explanation.. But as marc_s said i didnt work with `limit 1`. Is there an alternativ to Limit? Maybe i should have mentioned that the server i MSSQL..

Comment: It's also available in PostgreSQL.  Regardless, it's also possible to filter out all of the rows that aren't the global minimum via a subquery.

Comment: @Jack Maney 
I solved it like this then: 

`SELECT top 1 MIN(oe.prod_week) as te, oe.prodplan_id FROM pd_mounting_details as md LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id where oe.status=4 AND (md.starttime ='' or md.starttime is null) AND (a.production_group = 4) AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)) group by oe.prodplan_id order by te`

Found that TOP works instead..
Thanks for the help

Comment: Another question that poped up now.. If i want to use this as a subquery, how do i do then? I got an error saying "Only one expression can be specified in the select list" The value i want to retrive from the subquery is the `oe.prodplan_id` and use it in a term in the outer query? As of now i got both `te` and `oe.prodplan_id` ?

Comment: You mean using the entire query of yours above (`select top 1 min(oe.prod_week) as te,....order by te`) as a subquery? If so, how are you using it?

Comment: If i want something like this
`SELECT * FROM pd_prod_plans WHERE prodplan_id = (SELECT top 1 MIN(oe.prod_week) as te, oe.prodplan_id FROM pd_mounting_details as md LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id where oe.status=4 AND (md.starttime ='' or md.starttime is null) AND (a.production_group = 4) AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)) group by oe.prodplan_id order by te)`

Comment: As it looks now the subquery returns both `te` and `oe.prodplan_id` 
So i can understand why i get the error messsage, but is it possible to only get the `oe.prodplan_id` as the term to the outer question?

Comment: Sure, you can do `select * from pd_prod_plans where prodplan_id=(select prodplan_id from (select top 1 min(oe.prod_week) as te,oe.prodplan_id from...yada yada yada)`

Comment: Alright, that seems logical,, 
But when i try this

`Select prodplan_id FROM (SELECT top 1 MIN(oe.prod_week) as te, oe.prodplan_id FROM pd_mounting_details as md 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_ecolid AS oe ON md.order_data = oe.id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a ON md.article = a.id where oe.status=4 AND (md.starttime ='' or md.starttime is null) AND 
     (a.production_group = 4) AND (NOT oe.amount = 0) group by oe.prodplan_id order by te)`
I get an error saying: `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`
If i remove the outer SELECT i works.. Strange ?
O, it didn't work with `yada` ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being lazy...I should've just copied and pasted.

Comment: haha just a joke, real nice of you helping me.. Do you se why it doesn't work with the outer SQL?

Answer (score 4):

You are using `GROUP BY`, which means you will get one row per `GROUP`.

In this case your `GROUP` is `prodplan_id` and there are two matching values.

To get both values you can try:

```
SELECT oe.prod_week, oe.prodplan_id 
FROM pd_mounting_details as md 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_eco AS oe 
   ON md.order_data = oe.id 

WHERE oe.prod_week = (SELECT MIN(oe.prod_week)
                      FROM pd_mounting_details as md 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_order_eco AS oe 
                         ON md.order_data = oe.id
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN pd_article AS a 
                         ON md.article = a.id where oe.status=4 
                      AND (md.starttime ='' or md.starttime is null) 
                      AND (a.production_group = 4) 
                      AND (NOT (oe.amount = 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your select statement ends with a group by clause, you are selecting the minimum prod_week for each prodplan_id instead of the overall minimum. Remove the group by clause and it should work as you expect.